# Maxheap counting the total swaps needed when inputting an array [1 to N]

Tags: python, algorithm, heap

I need to count the total number of swaps needed to turn an array [1 to N] into maxheap. My code below outputs the correct answers but I was wondering if there was an alternative faster way to accomplish the same thing?

```
from math import floor, log2
 

def count(n):
    layers = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        layers += floor(log2(i))
    return layers
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(count(4)) # 4
    print(count(7)) # 10
    print(count(123)) # 618
```

Comment: *number of swaps* - what is swapped in your code and why the result should be called "maxheap" ?

Comment: Are you saying it **needs** 4 swaps to turn [1,2,3,4] into a valid max heap? Surely that can be done with 1 swap: swap 1 with 4, and you're done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1816275) Math StackExchange answer which, coupled with the base of 2 reducing the formula nicely, boils your function down to one formula:

```py
from math import floor, log2
 

def count(n):
    fl2n = floor(log2(n))
    return fl2n*(n+1) + 2 - 2**(fl2n+1)
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(count(4)) # 4
    print(count(7)) # 10
    print(count(123)) # 618
```

To further optimize, we also know that `floor(log2(n))` returns the biggest power of 2 smaller than `n`, which is exactly the bitlength of `n` - 1. This is because the biggest power of 2 smaller than `n` is the one where `2**n` has one bit in `n`'s most significant digit. `2**n` is also equal to `1 << n.bit_length()`. Using these, we don't even need to import the math module!

```py
def count(n):
    return (n.bit_length()-1)*(n+1) + 2 - (1 << n.bit_length()) if n > 0 else 0
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(count(4)) # 4
    print(count(7)) # 10
    print(count(123)) # 618
```